# Prove that the value of integral is 0

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Lef $f$ be a nonnegative real-valued function on $[0, 1]$ that is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ with integral $I \in \mathbb R$. Show that if $f=0$ on $[0, 1]\backslash D$ for some countable subset $D$ of $[0, 1]$, then $I=0$.

Note: **Do NOT use Lebesgue integration here.** I already know that $f=0$ a.e. here hence $I=0$ is the straightforward result. What I want to know is how to prove the same result using the definition and properties of Riemann integrability.

My attempt: I tried a special case when $D= \left\{\dfrac 1n : n\in \mathbb R\right\}$ as follows:

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, $f$ is bounded and let $M$ be an upper bound of $f$. Now consider a partition $P=\{0=x_0, x_1, ..., x_n=1\}$. Then for given $\epsilon>0$ and $x_1<\epsilon/2M$, all but finitely many elements of $D$ belong to the interval $[x_0, x_1]$. Then $M_1 = \mathrm {sup}\{f(x): x\in [x_0, x_1]\}\le M$ and $m_1=\mathrm{inf}\{f(x): x\in [x_0, x_1]\}=0$. Now $1, 1/2, ..., 1/N$ be $N$ elements which are not in $[x_0, x_1]$. Then construct a partition $P=\{0=x_0, x_1, ..., x_n=1\}$ such that $||P||=\sup_i\{x_{i+1}-x_i\}<\epsilon/2MN$ and $x_i \neq \dfrac1m$ for any $i$ and $m$. Then there are exactly $N$ number of $i$'s such that $\dfrac 1m\in [x_i, x_i+1]$. Therefore,\begin{align*}U(f, P)-L(f, P) &=M_1 \times \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(M_{i+1}-m_{i+1})(x_{i+1}-x_{i})\\&<M \times \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}+\sum_{i=1}^nM \dfrac{\epsilon}{2MN}\\&= \frac{\epsilon}2+ MN\dfrac{\epsilon}{2MN}\\&=\epsilon\end{align*}

Therefore, $f$ is Riemann integrable.

However, I have no idea how to generalize this proof. In this case we have only one limit point, $x=0$, but we cannot guarantee that there are only finitely many limit points of $D$ in general. Does anyone have other ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is actually quite easy. By hypothesis, we're assuming $f$ is integrable, which means

$$\int_a^b f = \sup\{L(f,P) : P \ \text{is a partition of} \ [a,b] \}$$

But all the lower sums are zero, since $f$ is nonnegative and any interval of the form $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ is uncountable. Hence $$\int_a^b f = 0$$

Comment: I think it's harder if you get rid of the nonnegative assumption.

Comment: Actually, no, it's easy then too, since $$0 \leq \left|\int_a^b f\right| \leq \int_a^b |f|$$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Oh I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

$f $ is integrable at $[0,1]  \implies \exists \delta>0 \;:$

for any partition $P=(x_0,x_1,...x_n)$ with $\|P\|=\max_{0\le i \le n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)<\delta $

all the Riemann sums $S=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f (\xi_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i) $, satisfy

$$|\int_0^1 f-S|<\epsilon. $$

You can choose $\xi_i \in [x_{i+1},x_i]\backslash D$ such that $f (\xi_i)=0$.

hence $|\int_0^1f -0|<\epsilon $.

You are nearly done.